# How to preserve a TED talk's subtitle and transcript language settings?

Tags: video, subtitles, ted

Right now I have the same question for videos on the TED Talks website [as I have for YouTube videos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25120/is-there-a-way-to-store-subtitle-settings-in-a-youtube-url):

**Is there any way to save/preserve the settings I make**, so that I can forward the video with the settings loading upon opening the URL on a different PC in a different country?

For example I want to set subtitles and transcripts for [this video](http://www.ted.com/talks/lang/en/chimamanda_adichie_the_danger_of_a_single_story.html) which has an `/en/` in it, but hard as I tried, another country short code is not available (the URL goes to nowhere) i.e. changing this part of the string doesn't help.

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it is possible by simply adding the string `/languagecode/` (e.g. `/en/` or `/de/`).

You just have to check beforehand if the subtitle already exists! The setting you **cannot** store though is the "interactive transcript". But once the language is set, the transcript—when opened—is set to that same language (i.e. the translation, not English) as well!

Example:
`http://www.ted.com/talks/tom_wujec_build_a_tower.html`
becomes
`http://www.ted.com/talks/lang/fr/tom_wujec_build_a_tower.html`

Comment: Is there any workaround to pass the 'textlocation-id' to the embedded video player in the htmlfile? 

This is to open the _video_ at the specific text using "interactive transcript" in TED.com. 

http://www.ted.com/talks/tom_wujec_build_a_tower.html#71000

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking about building a URL, that can be sent to someone else, that will both (a) automatically display subtitle/caption and (b) make the transcript immediately visible below, for a particular language, eg, German, you can add this string behind a normal TED Talk URL:

/transcript?language=de

For example,

https://www.ted.com/talks/ken_robinson_how_to_escape_education_s_death_valley

becomes

https://www.ted.com/talks/ken_robinson_how_to_escape_education_s_death_valley/transcript?language=de

In your particular example, note that today it has been redirected to a URL with the parameter "?language=en". In this case, you need to replace "?language=en" with "/transcript?language=de" if the targeted language is German.

https://www.ted.com/talks/chimamanda_adichie_the_danger_of_a_single_story?language=en

becomes

https://www.ted.com/talks/chimamanda_adichie_the_danger_of_a_single_story/transcript?language=de

The actual language code in the above examples is "de". Other examples are "zh-cn" for Chinese Simplified, "id" for Indonesian, and "es" for Spanish.

How to find out more language codes?

On the general listing page (https://www.ted.com/talks), select the "Languages" drop down select list, then any of the videos, and its URL should end with something like "?language=ja" if you have selected Japanese in the drop down list. In this case, you've found that "ja" is the language code for Japanese on TED Talks site.

Not all TED Talks videos are translated. You can estimate the total number of translated videos in any language by looking at its listing page to see the maximum number of pages listed. Multiply the maximum page number by 36, as each page currently lists 36 videos.